# Criar uma curva ROC em R

Tags: r

Preciso plotar uma curva ROC em R, mas não sei como corrigir.

```
cctrl2 <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, classProbs = TRUE, savePredictions = TRUE)
modelNb <- train(Treino[, -5], Treino$TOTAL_PEDIDO, 
             method = "nb", 
             trControl = cctrl2)
test_class_pred_nb_probs <- predict(modelNb, Teste[, -5], type = "prob")
roc_nb = plot.roc(Teste[, 2],test_class_pred_nb_probs$alto, col='red')
```

Porém a tabela de Teste$TOTAL_PEDIDO possui 4 valores(alto, regular, baixo e min) e para plotar a curva ROC o valor deve ser atômico. Portanto fiz o seguinte.

```
aux<-Teste[which(Teste$TOTAL_PEDIDO == "alto"),]
test_class_pred_nb_probs <- predict(modelNb, aux[, -5], type = "prob")
roc_nb = plot.roc(aux[, 2],test_class_pred_nb_probs$alto, col='red')
```

E aparece a mensagem:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
```

Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Answer (score 2):

A mudança no código é o uso da função multiclass.roc, pois o atributo TOTAL_PEDIDO é multivalorado.

```
cctrl2 <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,  classProbs = TRUE, 
savePredictions = TRUE)

modelNb <- train(Treino[, -2], Treino$TOTAL_PEDIDO,
          method = "nb", 
          trControl = cctrl2)

test_pred_nb <- predict(modelNb, Teste[, -2])
test_pred_nb_probs <- predict(modelNb, Teste[, -2], type = "prob")
roc_nb = multiclass.roc(Teste[, 2],
 test_pred_nb_probs$min,
 add=TRUE,
 col='blue')
roc_nb
rs <- roc_nb[['rocs']]
plot.roc(rs[[1]])

auc(roc_nb)
```

Comment: A mudança no código é o uso da função multiclass.roc, pois o atributo TOTAL_PEDIDO é multivalorado.